# VLC crashes when playing HDR videos after upgrade to Ubuntu 20.10

Tags: upgrade, video, vlc, crash, 20.10

I just upgraded my system to Ubuntu 20.10, and now I cannot play 10 bit `yuv420p10le` format videos anymore. This problem occurs with both HEVC and AV1 codec videos. Both videos played in VLC before the upgrade. When I run VLC from a terminal, I get an error:

```
[00007fd6a000b170] chain filter error: Too high level of recursion (3)
[00007fd6a000aa10] main filter error: Failed to create video converter
```

This message appears no matter what video output I select, and when I use the OpenGL output, I get various OpenGL related errors. Some video output options lead to a segfault, while others just don't play anything. I can play these files in `ffplay`, but since they are HDR, the colors don't look right.

**Steps to reproduce:** make sure you have VLC 3.0.11.1 installed. Find any video file, then run the following command on it:

```
ffmpeg -i "your video file" -color_primaries bt2020 -pix_fmt yuv420p10 -codec copy ./output.mkv
```

The resulting file should cause VLC to crash. (NOTE: you could replace `bt2020` with any valid color primaries, and you will still get the same result)

These are the `mediainfo` outputs for the files in question ()they are both the same video, just encoded with different codecs)

HEVC version:

```
Format                                   : HEVC
Format/Info                              : High Efficiency Video Coding
Format profile                           : Main 10@L4@Main
Codec ID                                 : V_MPEGH/ISO/HEVC
Duration                                 : 1 min 53 s
Bit rate                                 : 96.0 Mb/s
Width                                    : 1 920 pixels
Height                                   : 1 080 pixels
Display aspect ratio                     : 16:9
Frame rate mode                          : Constant
Frame rate                               : 30.000 FPS
Color space                              : YUV
Chroma subsampling                       : 4:2:0
Bit depth                                : 10 bits
Bits/(Pixel*Frame)                       : 1.543
Stream size                              : 1.27 GiB (98%)
Writing library                          : x265 2.8:[Linux][GCC 7.3.0][64 bit] 10bit
Default                                  : Yes
Forced                                   : No
Color range                              : Full
Color primaries                          : BT.2020
Transfer characteristics                 : HLG
Matrix coefficients                      : BT.2020 non-constant
```

AV1 version:

```
Format                                   : AV1
Format/Info                              : AOMedia Video 1
Format profile                           : Main
Codec ID                                 : V_AV1
Duration                                 : 1 min 53 s
Bit rate                                 : 166 Mb/s
Width                                    : 1 920 pixels
Height                                   : 1 080 pixels
Display aspect ratio                     : 16:9
Frame rate mode                          : Constant
Frame rate                               : 30.000 FPS
Color space                              : YUV
Chroma subsampling                       : 4:2:0
Bit depth                                : 10 bits
Bits/(Pixel*Frame)                       : 2.673
Stream size                              : 2.20 GiB (98%)
Default                                  : Yes
Forced                                   : No
Color range                              : Full
Color primaries                          : BT.2020
Transfer characteristics                 : HLG
Matrix coefficients                      : BT.2020 non-constant
```

**EDIT:** I have done some test, and figured out that any video will play, as long as the color space specified in the file is not bt2020. I also noticed that if I download this file after uploading it to youtube, it will play correctly, despite having the bt2020 color space in the metadata.

Comment: @Rinzwind It must have been released, since I got the option to upgrade to it yesterday, and I did (I do not have upgrade to development releases enabled). Also, how do I file a bug report for VLC, and if it gets fixed, will it come as an update through apt, or will I have to re-compile it myself?

Comment: @Rinzwind 20.10 has been released. https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/19374/1103140

Comment: ah sorry this covid work at home totally got me absorbed in work :-D 1st release I have not installed on my machine before it got released D: ever.

Comment: Try gst-play-1.0, ffplay -loglevel 16, SMPlayer, and MPV.

Answer (score 1):

Have you try reset your preference (Tools > Preferences > Reset Preferences)?

I don't know if I have same case but a lot of my video also can not be played after I upgrade to 20.10 (the VLC just crash after brief moment I opened the file) and now it can be played again after I reset my setting.

Comment: Unfortunately the problem still occurs, even after resetting my preferences.

Answer (score 0):

after upgrading to ubuntu 20.10 vlc video did not play. audio was ok.
The problem was that ubuntu 20.10 used the x org video-cart drive.
After installing the original driver for the nvidia-cart everything functioned properly.